# Make an item appear yellow

Tags: html, css, class, jquery-mobile

I am having two lists, as you can see in the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/h7gxpqn0/41/). When the match is full, a player can inform the rest of the world that he wants to play, thus he can set himself as a waiting one. For that purpose I thought I could just paint that item yellow ( if you have some other suggestion, I would die to find out :) ). However, there is no effect.

Here is the CSS code:

```
.waiting {
    color: yellow !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to select the `<a>` element inside the `<li>` to change the text color

you can use the `<li>` to change the Background color etc...

e.g.:

```
.waiting a {
    color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: haha @MrLister sorry, will correct that. That worked, but why?

Comment: @MrLister you got there before me

Comment: @gsamaras Why `.waiting a` works but `.waiting` by itself doesn't? Well, because `a` elements already have a colour of their own, which doesn't depend on a parent element (i.e. it is not inherited). You could also have solved the issue by writing `a {color:inherit}` in the stylesheet.

Comment: I think that Gotschi will be polite enough to edit it.